# What does & 0xff do And MD5 Structure?

Tags: java, md5

```
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;

public class JavaMD5 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String passwordToHash = "MyPassword123";
        String generatedPassword = null;
        try {
            MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update(passwordToHash.getBytes());
            byte[] bytes = md.digest();
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < bytes.length; i++) {
                sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
            }
            generatedPassword = sb.toString();

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        System.out.println(generatedPassword);
    }
}
```

This line is the problem :

```
sb.append(Integer.toString((bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100, 16).substring(1));
```

what does each part do in  this structure????

Thanks and I'm sorry for asking Beacuse I'm new in java.

Comment: This is a hacky way to ensure every byte gets represented as two hexadecimal digits.  It'd be equivalent to write `sb.append(String.format("%02x", bytes[i]))`.

Comment: How do you make sure it works the same way everywhere ... Like the character encoding might be different on different systems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Presumably most of the code is clear and the only mystery for you here is this expression:

```
(bytes[i] & 0xff) + 0x100
```

The first part:

```
bytes[i] & 0xff
```

widens the byte at position `i` to an `int` value with zeros in bit positions 8-31. In Java, the `byte` data type is a signed integer value, so the widening sign-extends the value. Without the `& 0xff`, values greater than 0x7f would end up as negative `int` values. The rest is then fairly obvious: it adds 0x100, which simply turns on the bit at index 8 (since it is guaranteed to be 0 in `(bytes[i] & 0xff)`. It is then converted to a hex `String` value by the call to `Integer.toString(..., 16)`.

The reason for first adding 0x100 and then stripping off the 1 (done by the `substring(1)` call, which takes the substring starting at position 1 through the end) is to guarantee two hex digits in the end result. Otherwise, byte values below 0x10 would end up as one-character strings when converted to hex.

It's debatable whether all that has better performance (it certainly isn't clearer) than:

```
sb.append(String.format("%02x", bytes[i]));
```

Answer (score 4):

It's a really messy way of translating to a hexadecimal string.

- `& 0xFF` performs a binary AND, causing the returning value to be between 0 and 255 (which a byte always is anyway)
- `+ 0x100` adds 256 to the result to ensure the result is always 3 digits
- `Integer.toString(src, 16)` converts the integer to a string with helix 16 (hexadecimal)
- Finally `.substring(1)` strips the first character (the `1` from step 2)

So, this is a very elaborate and obfuscated way to convert a byte to an always 2-character hexadecimal string.

Comment: And why would one want to do this ? Any simpler way to do it ? Any online resource matching this ?